# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP if querystring parameter is absent via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect HTTPS to HTTP *only* if the following querystring parameters are absent:

`https://www.example.com/index.php?p=login

https://www.example.com/index.php?p=signup

https://www.example.com/index.php?p=cart

https://www.example.com/index.php?p=one_page_checkout`

That is, any querystring *other* than these should redirect from HTTPS to HTTP. I want to make sure only my checkout path is HTTP.

Can this be done simply using `.htaccess` with `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules that may already be there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)p=(login|signup|cart|one_page_checkout)(&|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=(login|signup|cart|one_page_checkout)(&|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

To make this a permanent redirect, add a `=301` after the `R` in the square brackets.

Comment: That mostly works...but if I go to `http://www.example.com/index.php?p=cart` it does not redirect to *HTTPS*.

Comment: Can this be made to work with rules that redirect www to no-www?

Comment: @larpo just redirect www to no-www in a separate rule before these

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)p=(login|signup|cart|one_page_checkout)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put below lines into your .htaccess file :-

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```