# Forcing Non-SSL when specific url parameter is given

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, ssl

Ok I found out that I can force users to use SSL by changing something in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Deny Access to all .htaccess
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

I'm not really good in writing .htaccess files so i most likely copy-paste it from the internet.

My question is if it's possible to always force ssl with one exception (When someone is visiting a http site with a specific url parameter).

Example 1:

```
http://example.com/test?name=John
```

gets redirected to

```
https://example.com/test?name=John
```

Example 2:

```
http://example.com/test?name=John&nossl=1
```

doesn't get redirected to

```
https://example.com/test?name=John&nossl=1
```

Is it possible to write that in htaccess or do i need to include a php file to every single page that's doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a [DUPLICATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854658/redirect-https-to-http-if-querystring-parameter-is-absent-via-htaccess)

BTW

Put this before the `# Force SSL` condition.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)nossl=(1)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: i'm sorry i was searching for it but haven't found it

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me if anyone has the same problem(redirects every link to ssl / if nossl=1 it redirects to http if needed):

```
# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)nossl=(1)(&|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Force Non-SSL if URL parameter nossl=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)nossl=(1)(&|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```